# Casting a double to a DateTime type is off by 2 days?

Tags: c#, sql

I store datetime values in the database as sql float type (Converted from an DateTime.OADate) for a myriad of reasons however in certain circumstances it is nice to get a human readable date/time column back from the database.  I have found that I can execute the statement

```
SELECT CAST (timerecorded_utc as DATETIME) FROM tablename
```

and it will give me the date time string I am looking for but it seems to be off by exactly 2 days. I realize I can just modify the statement (since in time represented as a double 1 day = 1.0) to be

```
SELECT CAST (timerecorded_utc-2.0 as DATETIME) FROM tablename
```

BUT I was wondering if this is consistent AND it seems to me there is some reason for the discrepancy that I am missing.

Comment: Could it be your lost some precision when saving the data to the database ?

Comment: I dont think it is precision related because the time down to the millisecond is correct.  The days are calculated before the decimal point and the Time comes from the values after the decimal point. If it was precision related, the time would be wrong (at least I think)

Comment: @Matthew, what does the date-to-float conversion look like?

Comment: @Matthew - Is this SQL Server or Oracle?

Comment: This is MS SQL Server and actually SQL CE (if that matters they both behave the same)

Comment: As for the conversions back and forth I use DateTime.ToOADate(DateTime) and DateTime.FromOADate(double).  My understanding is that a SQL "float" equals a c# double

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because the epochs the dates use are different.

SQL Server's DATETIME uses 01/01/1900 00:00:00 as the epoch, which you can see by running the following query: `SELECT CAST(0 AS DATETIME)`

OADate is a bit odd, as it could have an epoch of 30/12/1899 00:00:00 or 31/12/1899 00:00:00 depending on whether you believe the Visual Basic or Excel guys, respectively. It would appear that from your two day difference, the .NET version goes with the 30th.

So, epoch off by two days gives two days difference in the outcome when you convert between the two types of date via a raw number.

Comment: Anyone know if there's any method to this madness?

Comment: Awesome Why didn't I think of this... If I run DateTime.FromOADate(0.0) I get 12/30/1899 12:00:00 AM Thank you!!!!

Comment: Excel also has a "feature"&mdash; intentionally carried forward from Lotus 1-2-3!&mdahs;wherein the leap rule rule was incorrectly implement. The correct leap year rule is

Comment: Excel also has a "feature"&mdash; intentionally carried forward from Lotus 1-2-3!&mdash;wherein the leap rule rule was incorrectly implement. The correct leap year rule is that leap years are those years divisible by 4 that are not also divisible by 100, unless divisible by 400 (eg. 2004 is a leap year, 2000 is a leap year, but 1900 is not a leap year). Lotus 1-2-3 and Excel incorrectly assume that all years divisible by 4 are leap years. See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/214326 for more details.

Comment: @Lee - Joel Spolsky wrote about some of the history here: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2006/06/16.html

Comment: For more background on this issue, see my article on the subject: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/09/16/53013.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Epic Epochs... Here is my TSQL solution in SQL Server using the built in
"DateAdd" function:

```
Select DateAdd(DAY, cast([ENDING DATE] as decimal(10,0)), '12/30/1899')
from YourTable
```

In my case I was importing a string saved in Excel via C# Core App and uploading to a SQL Server database so my [Ending Date] is a string which I casted as a decimal with no precision as I only needed the actual date, and not the time of day. As @GregBeech mentioned, your base date might be '12/31/1899'.