# How can I format a column as a date using spreadsheetFormatColumn?

Tags: excel, date, coldfusion, spreadsheet

I'm using cfspreadsheet to generate an excel sheet of data. There are a couple of columns that are dates, and are displaying like this:

```
1988-09-19 00:00:00.0
```

I'd like to format them to display in m/d/yyyy format. I tried using spreadsheetFormatColumn:

```
<cfset spreadsheetFormatColumn(s, {dataformat="m/d/yyyy"}, 8) />
```

But it doesn't change anything. How can I format the column using coldfusion?

Comment: What is your full CF version and how are you populating the sheet?

Comment: @Leigh - I'm using CF9. I'm populating the sheet using "spreadsheetAddRows" and a query object

Comment: What is the full version number 9.x.x? There were some changes in update 1. Prior to that it did not always respect the format. So you had to use workarounds. (Courtesy note, I have to run off to a meeting right :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Leigh mentioned in a comment, this seems to be a coldfusion bug. I got around this by converting the dates to varchars on the sql server side (using `convert(varchar, myDateField, 101)`).

Answer (score 0):

It may not be a bug. The value you put into a cell, using the spreadsheet functions, needs to be a `float` and not any kind of date string like "12/25/2012".

The float should represent **the number of days since the epoch**, which my research found that Excel treats `1` as `1/1/1900 00:00:00`.  However, there were [other odd results out there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5995256/casting-a-double-to-a-datetime-type-is-off-by-2-days) as well that said that sometimes the epoch was a day or two off of that.

The method I found [to represent this in Oracle](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=379913) is:

```
   SELECT ( TRUNC(inv_date) - TO_DATE('1899-12-30', 'yyyy-mm-dd') ) 
          +  TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(inv_date, 'SSSSS')) / 86400 AS InvcDateAsFloat
```

(Note that there are two places, represented by `inv_date`, to put in the name of your own date column)

Comment: I disagree. It sounds like the OP was using date/time objects, not strings. Date objects like `now()` are already numbers internally and work just fine with POI. So there is no reason *date objects* cannot work right out of the box with CF.

Comment: Leigh, maybe you're right. It might be a bug.  I changed my verbiage. I was also using date/time columns in my db, which I thought was along the same lines as the OP.

Comment: Yeah, date/time values should work "as is" imo (obviously they do not though). Btw, on windows Excel treats 1 as `1/1/1900`, so you may want to double check the date logic above. From what I have read about mac's, [older versions](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/303216) default to the 1904 date system instead of 1900.

Comment: The code I entered above works for me.  My Oracle is 8, and I'm using the spreadsheet functions from CF 9.0.1

Comment: I am not running Oracle, so I will take your word for it :) But as far as Excel, `1` is actually treated as `01/01/1900` on windows (not `12/30/1899' - and supposedly as 1904 on some mac systems.

Comment: I get the same result in Excel (it's also funny how it formats a 0 as `Jan 0, 1900`). Maybe it's a math/off-by-one thing since we're doing date subtraction and that's just the way these functions work.